# Display Query Result Parse.com android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a question, it might sound like silly question, But I really don't know how and need an answer.

In parse.com after finishing query, how can I display the result

For example this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> gameQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Game");
gameQuery.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
```

I want to set the result of the query to some text view in my app:
`textview.setText(??)`;

Thank you in advance :)

**Edit:**

and this is the code I'm using

```
public class Adapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {
//MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public Adapter(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Game");
            return query;
        }
    });
}

// Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
@Override
public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    // I'm getting Images from Game class
    ParseImageView audioImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("img");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        audioImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        audioImage.loadInBackground();
    }//end if


    //retrieving Titles from Game Class
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("title"));


    //Now I want to retrieve name from User Class :(
    // the code is crashing my app
    //?????????????????????????????????????????????????

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> userQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Game");
    userQuery.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                ParseObject userName = list.get(0); // Gets first object

                // You can get fields using the get() method
                ParseUser user = (ParseUser) userName.get("createdBy");

                // There are data specific methods as well
                String firstName = user.getString("name");

                nameTextView.setText(firstName);
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    });





    return v;
}//end getItem View

}//end custom Adapator
```

Comment: Use findInBackground to execute the query, and pass a callback to handle the result. in the callback you will display somehting in a textview https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> gameQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Game");
gameQuery.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
gameQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> gameList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ParseObject game = gameList.get(0); // Gets first object

            // You can get fields using the get() method
            ParseUser user = game.get("createdBy");

            // There are data specific methods as well
            String firstName = user.getString("userFirstName");

            textview.setText(firstName);
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Above is an example only. See the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html) for `ParseObject` for all the `get*()` methods for getting data from an object.

Some common ones are: `get()`, `getString()`, `getBoolean`, etc.

**UPDATE:**

First, you'll have to tell your query to fetch the pointer data as well (Parse does not include pointer data for queries by default). That is why your app crashes. So update your query to this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> userQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Game");
userQuery.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
userQuery.include("createdBy");
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public class Adapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {
    //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public Adapter(Context context) {

        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Game");
                userQuery.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                query.include("createdBy");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    // Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
    @Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

        // I'm getting Images from Game class
        ParseImageView audioImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("img");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            audioImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            audioImage.loadInBackground();
        }//end if


        //retrieving Titles from Game Class
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        titleTextView.setText(object.getString("title"));


        //Now I want to retrieve name from User Class :(
        // the code is crashing my app
        //?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        // You can get fields using the get() method
        ParseUser user = (ParseUser) object.get("createdBy");

        // There are data specific methods as well
        String firstName = user.getString("name");

        nameTextView.setText(firstName);

        return v;
    }//end getItem View

}//end custom Adapator
```

Comment: Yes, as I said, the code above is as an example. If you could show some more of your code and what you want to get done more specifically in the question, I could give more specific an answer. The objectId can be accessed using the `getObjectId()` method.

Comment: See update above. And yes, you can cast. Also, to access all the objects in the list, use a loop like @McGuile's answer.

Comment: The zero is then index at which you want to get the ParseObject from the list (like accessing an array). You can get the objectId using this: `game.getObjectId()`

Comment: Maybe update 2 is what you need. You already have a query which gets the Games in your `public ParseQuery create()` method. Add the `.include("createdBy")` there. You then may not be needing another query in `getItemView`

Comment: I'll see what I can do. I know Parse but don'y have much experience with multimedia. But I'm sure there's plenty people on the SO community who would love to help.

Comment: Updated above. Added the `userQuery.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());` line in `create()`

Comment: can you help me on this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418291/i-cant-update-users-information-on-parse-com-android  XD

Comment: OK. Will have a look.