# How to update User information on Parse.com, in Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to update user's information on parse.com, and it worked perfectly one time and it never works anymore. I don't know why.

Here is my code.

```
ParseUser pu = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
String userID = pu.getObjectId();

ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground(userID, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            String playerName= displayNameEditText.getText().toString();
            parseUser.put("playerName", playerName);
            String teamName= emailEditText.getText().toString();
            parseUser.put("teamName", teamName);
            String phone = phoneEditText.getText().toString();
            parseUser.put("phone", phone);


            parseUser.saveInBackground();
        }

    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do a saveInBackground with a callback and log the error.

Comment: I didn't get your suggestion .. how to do that ?

Comment: Just like you're doing a getInBackground with a callback, do a saveInBackground with a callback. The method should autocomplete.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm not doing it right . It suggests to add qualifier to method

Comment: There are examples on the parse website if you can't figure out the method.

Comment: I did it and then the app crashes !

Comment: @AdamahNour why are you doing a `getInBackground` for the user? `getCurrentUser()` will get you your currently logged in user object.

Comment: @kRiZ hmm so shall I remove getInBackground  with its method " done" and directly set my updates ?

Comment: @AdamahNour yes, remove it because it is not required. And post any errors you get. Also, is it this same code which used to work before?